# How to unit test DataRow with a lot of columns in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, mocking

What is the best way to unit test DataRows in C#?

I have a class architecture where all data is stored inside DataRow variable. How it works? For example when i double click on one record in the customers list the whole record from Customer table i loaded into _dataRow variable.
The problem is that Customer table has over 200 columns.

The question is, do I need to manually create DataRow variable and fill all columns in every test method? Or maybe there is some mocking tool to mock all DataRow columns?

```
class Customer
{
    private DataRow _dataRow;

    public Customer(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        _dataRow = dataRow;
    }

    private string GetCustomerName()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(_dataRow["Name"]);
    }

    private string GetCustomerAddress()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(_dataRow["Street"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(_dataRow["House_No"]);
    }

    private int GetAge()
    {
        DateTime birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(_dataRow["Birthdate"]);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year - birthdate.Year;
        if (birthdate > today.AddYears(-age))
            age--;
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a hardcoded datatable with a record and inject the datarow in the unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mock/set up *every* column of the DataRow in *every* test. Each test should only be testing a small piece of functionality, and therefore should only use a subset of the 200 columns.

Any column that affects the output of the test should be explicitly set up or mocked (i.e. no shortcuts!). If a particular column does not affect the output of the test, but is still required to be set (in order to prevent exceptions to be thrown for example), then maybe you need to rethink the design of the class.

If, after considering this, you *still* need to set up all 200 columns in every test, then consider creating a method that create a data row filled with 200 default values, and then override the values that are important for that particular test. As per paragraph 1, this should only be a small subset of the 200 columns in each test.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds logic. I'll use a subset of the 200 columns, only these which tested method need.